# How to merge rows that are multiples of 3 in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I have this sheet:

[image]

I want to merge rows that are multiples of 3(i.e 3,6,9,etc.).

Comment: Is this possible using excel formula?

Comment: Do you want to merge the cells or have A3 read "Major Revision in Services page"

Comment: Yes I want A3 to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an Excel-VBA-question. You should change the tag.

A1: [Empty]

A2: =INT(Row(A2)/3)+15

A3: =trim(C2&" "&D2&" "&E2&" "&F2&" "&G2&" "&H2")

Mark A1:A3 and drag down